# Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 on Java app

Tags: cryptography, wildfly, java, alpine-linux

I have a Java 8 application raising the following exception when connecting a ldaps or a https server:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
    Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
```

My client environment is:

```
Alpine Linux 3.5 on a Docker container
OpenJDK 1.8.0_111
Wildfly 10.1.0.Final
```

I can workaround this problem if I connect from:

- An Alpine Linux box using AES128-SHA cipher (TLSv1)
- A container with CentOS 7 instead of Alpine Linux 3.5 (all ciphers work)

But will always fail if I connect from:

- An Alpine Linux box using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 cipher (TLSv1.2)

Is there something suggested to fix this problem on my Alpine Linux installation?

Comment: Additional information:  curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 is also known as "secp256r1" or which is also called "P-256" by NIST. It **is** available in Oracle's Java Standard Runtime Environment since Java 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL,DR**: OpenJDK 8 package from Alpine doesn't support ciphers that use elliptic curve, like `ECDHE`. Use `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false` on Java options to kindly ask OpenJDK to not use such ciphers.

This nice Atlassian [paper](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html) describes how to list all default and available ciphers from JVM using the following code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class Ciphers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        String[] defaultCiphers = ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        String[] availableCiphers = ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();

        TreeMap ciphers = new TreeMap();

        for(int i=0; i<availableCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(availableCiphers[i], Boolean.FALSE);

        for(int i=0; i<defaultCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(defaultCiphers[i], Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println("Default\tCipher");
        for(Iterator i = ciphers.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry cipher=(Map.Entry)i.next();

            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(cipher.getValue()))
                System.out.print('*');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            System.out.print('\t');
            System.out.println(cipher.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code on OpenJDK 8 from Alpine 3.5 doesn't list any `ECDHE` cipher, on the other side this same code lists several such ciphers from OpenJDK 8 installed on a CentOS 7 box.

For some reason ciphers that use elliptic curve are sent from the client to the server as available ciphers on a Wildfly application. Outside Wildfly - eg `java SomeClass` or `java -jar some.jar` these ciphers aren't send and the communication works. This behavior can be observed adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` on Java options.

Comment: Do you have any idea why elliptic curves are not supported by our build of OpenJDK/IcedTea and how to fix it? We have not disabled this purposely.

Comment: They probably added a JCA provider that did include support for ECC such as the Bouncy Castle provider. Oracles provider is native and ECC is a IP minefield - where **most** of the patents have aged away. But those could be reasons not to include it.

Comment: @JakubJirutka See my answer below, and the associated Alpine defect. Looks like this will be resolved shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Alpine Linux 3.5's openjdk8-jre-base package 8.111.14-r1 doesn't include libsunec.so, the library that the SunEC provider looks for, but Alpine Linux 3.3 (8.92.14-r0) and 3.4 (8.111.14-r0) do (see [this package search](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libsunec.so&path=&name=&branch=&repo=&arch=x86_64)). I've opened [Alpine issue #6809](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/6809) for this.

The easiest way to work around this is probably to roll back to Alpine 3.4. Alternatively, you can install the 3.4 version of openjdk8-jre-base in 3.5, but you may run into some dependency issues if you go down this route.

If you want to use the Alpine Linux 3.5 package, you could have your java application use an alternate JCE provider like BouncyCastle.

If you don't need EC cryptography, you can disable it, but be warned that doing so will preclude your application from using several common PFS cipher suites.